# Mindstorms program error when I play in download mode

Tags: mindstorms, programming, robot-inventor

I can run the program perfectly in the streaming mode, but it will flash a red light in the download mode after getting 5 points. Below is my program code:

[image: program code]

...........Updated.............

Finally I solved it when I delete 2 define function and group in the program start. But I don't know why it work.
[image: work now]

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is due to nested custom blocks. I tried designing a very modular program once, but it would not download at all, and I believe it's because there were too many nested blocks. However, I cannot confirm this as it seems LEGO has published little to no comprehensive information on it's software.